# Using \hfill in tabbing environment

Tags: tabbing, hfill

I'd like to use `\hfill` within a tabbing environment, but it seems to have no effect. How can I do it?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabbing}
Foo bar baz: \= Lib  \hfill Bizim\\
Foo: \> Kip\\
\end{tabbing}

Foo bar baz: Lib  \hfill Bizim

Foo: Kip

\end{document}
```

(I can for some reason not upload a screen shot, as I get an error message "Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server")

Comment: (image upload seems to be broken, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382854/image-uploading-fails-with-failed-to-upload-image-an-error-occurred-on-the-ser)

Comment: Any reason to use tabbing instead of some kind of tabular?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Primarily because I had already used `\hfill` in my document before adding `tabbing`. Plus, how would I get the rightmost column in a table to be right aligned with the page margin?

Comment: I don't see how any of these points would contradict using a table

Comment: but `\hfill` is outside the tabbing environment in your MWE

Comment: @DanielDiniz ? No, it's not(?)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use a tabular environment of some kind. Here an example with the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} % just to show that the text is aligned with the margin
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{@{}lX@{}}
Foo bar baz: & Lib  \hfill Bizim\\
Foo: & Kip\\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe right align `` \` `` has the effect you intend

```
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace{0.2\textwidth} \= \hspace{0.2\textwidth} \= \hspace{0.2\textwidth}  \kill   % \kill lets the definition line disappear
Foo bar baz: \> Lib \` right aligned Bizim\\
Foo: \> Kip \> Bizim \\
\end{tabbing}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to be the easiest solution.

Comment: It would be good if the person who downvoted this explains why this is not a good solution ...

Answer (score 1):

You can measure the text by `\tabset` macro and use the text to measured width by `\tabuse`. You need not tabbing environment.

```
\newdimen\tabw
\def\tabset#1{\par \setbox0=\hbox{#1}\tabw=\wd0 \leavevmode\box0 }
\def\tabuse#1{\par \leavevmode\hbox to\tabw{#1\hss}}

\tabset {Foo bar baz:} \ Lib  \hfill Bizim
\tabuse {Foo:}         \ Kip
```